# Character returns as 11 instead of B. For loop error

Tags: java, for-loop, charat

I'm trying to make a name generator based on George Lucas' formula for to create the names for the characters in his stories (Jar Jar Binks, ObiWan Kenobi etc.).

Printing out the name in lower case works fine. What I'm trying to do, is to get the first character in each word to become capitalized.

Example:

First name *Bruce*,
last name *Wayne*,
mothers maiden name *Kane*,
city/town born *Gotham*.

My lower case test prints out:
*waybr kagot*

When returning the name it should return:
*Waybr Kagot* instead it returns... *11aybr Kagot*

I can't seem too find what causes this error. I hope someone can help me out :)

```
public class NameGenerator {

public NameGenerator()
{

}

public String generateStarWarsName(String firstName, String lastName, String motherMaidenName, String cityBorn)
{
    String first = firstName.toLowerCase();
    String last = lastName.toLowerCase();
    String maiden = motherMaidenName.toLowerCase();
    String city = cityBorn.toLowerCase();

    String myStarWarsFirstName = last.substring(0, 3) + first.substring(0, 2);
    String myStarWarsLastName = maiden.substring(0, 2) + city.substring(0, 3);
    String myStarWarsNameInLowerCase = myStarWarsFirstName + " " + myStarWarsLastName;

    // Test the name
    System.out.println(myStarWarsNameInLowerCase);

    // Make first character in word uppercase
    String myStarWarsName = myStarWarsNameInLowerCase.trim();
    int lengthOfName = myStarWarsName.length();
    char c = Character.toUpperCase(myStarWarsName.charAt(0));
    myStarWarsName = lengthOfName + myStarWarsName.substring(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfName; i++) {
        if (myStarWarsName.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            c = Character.toUpperCase(myStarWarsName.charAt(i + 1));
            myStarWarsName = myStarWarsName.substring(0, i) + " " + c + myStarWarsName.substring(i + 2);
        }
    }
    return myStarWarsName;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well why are you using `lengthOfName + myStarWarsName.substring(1);`? Shouldn't that be `c + myStarWarsName.substring(1)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you! That was the error. Been twisting my head around this for a while and couldn't see it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the line where you are concatenating the length of the line to the first name:

```
myStarWarsName = lengthOfName + myStarWarsName.substring(1);
```

Which translates to:

Make the String declared as myStarWarsName from a combination of the integer length of the string and the substring of myStarwarsName starting at the second position in the myStarWarsName String.

Change it to the following to capitalize only the first charater of the String:

```
myStarWarsName = myStarWarsName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + myStarWarsName.substring(1);
```

which will capitalize the first letter of the name.

You can take it a step farther and capitalize the first letter of each name by splitting the name at spaces, then for each name concatenate it to the end of the myStarWarsName field:

```
            String myStarWarsName = new String("obi wan kenobi");
            String[] names = myStarWarsName.split(" ");
            String result = new String();
            for(String name : names){
                name = name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
                result.concat(name).concat(" ");
            }
            myStarWarsName = result.trim();
            //myStarWarsName is now "Obi Wan Kenobi"
```